# Accesing Individual Frames using AV Player

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, avplayer

In a recent project, I have to access all frames of my video individually using AV Foundation. Also, if possible to acess them randomly (like an array)

I tried to research the question but I didn't get anything useful.

Note: Is there any useful documentation to get familiar with the AV Foundation ?

Comment: I can answer you for any question. But you have to explain more your question/Problem..

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to access individual frames of my video. Because I need to apply some magic algorithm in each frame by itself.

Comment: you want to play video in different frames???

Comment: yes, I got it now. You want to access frames of videos. right??

Comment: You will get images.

Comment: Yes you are right, I want to acess frames of videos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enumerate the frames of your video serially using `AVAssetReader`, like this:

```
let asset = AVAsset(URL: inputUrl)
let reader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: asset)

let videoTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

// read video frames as BGRA
let trackReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings:[String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)])

reader.addOutput(trackReaderOutput)
reader.startReading()

while let sampleBuffer = trackReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
    print("sample at time \(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer))")
    if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        // process each CVPixelBufferRef here
        // see CVPixelBufferGetWidth, CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress, etc
    }
}
```

Random access is more complicated. You could use an `AVPlayer` + `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` to get frames from any time `t`, using `copyPixelBufferForItemTime`, [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553034/22147), but the subtlety lies in how you choose that `t`.

If you want to sample the video at uniform intervals, then that's easy, but if you want to land on the same frames/presentation time stamps that the serial `AVAssetReader` code sees, then you will probably have to preprocess the file *with* `AVAssetReader`, to build a frame number -> presentation timestamp map. This can be fast if you skip decoding by using `nil` output settings in `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`.

Comment: Does this give all frames of my video ?

Comment: The `AVAssetReader` method does. If you know all the frame timestamps, the "random access" method should too.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. One question(s), can you provide with a documentation about  CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer because I still don't get it. Also, is there a way to save locally them so that I check what is happenning ?

Comment: There's some info in the `CMSampleBuffer` header file. It returns a `CVPixelBufferRef` from which you can get width, height and a pointer to pixels. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8072208/22147  for `CVPixelBuffer`->`UIImage`.

Comment: Thanks. If I have any problem I will write to you.

Comment: Hi Fistman, I have another question please. For the AVAssetReader is meant for offline (not real time) what about getting them in real time ?

Comment: What do you mean by realtime?

Comment: Assume I have a video on a server and I can play it on a local player. What I need is to acess its frames on real time (while it is playing for example) and apply some magic on it.

Comment: AVAssetReader only does local files, so you need AVPlayer + videooutput.

Comment: Can you explain how to do so please ? And if you have any documentation about it please let me know.

Comment: The explanation is in the answer? Maybe start a new question with these new details.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the current frame while playing the video you could add an observer for the player and could get the current frame like this:

```
var player: AVPlayer?
var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
var videoFPS: Int = 0
var currentFrame: Int = 0
var totalFrames: Int?

func configureVideo() {
    guard let videoURL = "" else { return }
    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    playerController.player = player
    guard player?.currentItem?.asset != nil else {
        return
    }
    let asset = self.player?.currentItem?.asset
    let tracks = asset!.tracks(withMediaType: .video)
    let fps = tracks.first?.nominalFrameRate
    
    self.videoFPS = lround(Double(fps!))
    self.getVideoData()
}
  
func getVideoData() {
    self.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(value: 1,timescale: Int32(self.videoFPS)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) {[weak self] (progressTime) in

        if let duration = self!.player?.currentItem?.duration {

            let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
            if self!.totalFrames == nil {
                self!.totalFrames = lround(Double(self!.videoFPS) * durationSeconds)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self!.totalFrames != self!.currentFrame {
                    self!.currentFrame = lround(seconds*Double(self!.videoFPS))
                } else {
                    print("Video has ended!!!!!!!!")
                }
                print(self!.currentFrame)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After getting the current frame number, you could use `AVAssetImageGenerator` to retrieve the specific image.