# CoreGraphics CGImage from CGDisplayStream weird colors

Tags: c++, core-graphics, screenshot, cgimage

Im currently using the CoreGraphics API for the first time (mainly C++ code) and i try to get a thumbnail (or "screenshot") out of a CGDisplayStream, which works fine except for the colors.

I create the CGDisplayStream using `CGDisplayStreamCreate()` [(documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455170-cgdisplaystreamcreate?language=objc) and use the `IOSurfaceRef` inside the handler block [(see this)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgdisplaystreamframeavailablehandler?language=objc) to create the CGImageRef.
Here is my testing code:

```
CVPixelBufferRef p_buffer = NULL;
CFDictionaryRef attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CVReturn ret = CVPixelBufferCreateWithIOSurface(kCFAllocatorDefault, surface, attributes, &p_buffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(p_buffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);

void* baseAddr = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(p_buffer);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(p_buffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(p_buffer);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef cgContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddr, width, height, 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(p_buffer), colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cgContext);
```

The call to create the CGDisplayStream looks like this:

```
CGDisplayStreamCreate(CGMainDisplayID(), 1920, 1080, 'BGRA', NULL,
                     ^(CGDisplayStreamFrameStatus status, uint64_t time, IOSurfaceRef surface, CGDisplayStreamUpdateRef metadata){ //above handler snipped is in here });
```

**I suspect either the pixelFormat [(see this)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers?language=objc) or the CGColorSpace is producing my weird output, but im not sure. I also do not know what i could do now except blindly guessing some random settings.
Maybe someone could give me a clue?**

Here is my output vs a "real" screenshot.

[image: This is my output]
[image: This is a "real" screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Finaly found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072208/how-to-turn-a-cvpixelbuffer-into-a-uiimage/8094038):

I changed the line

```
CGContextRef cgContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddr, width, height, 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(p_buffer), colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
```

to

```
CGContextRef cgContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddr, width, height, 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(p_buffer), colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
```

and now it is working fine.

It is still not very clear to me why this is a solution. I guess a bit more in-depth knowledge of image formats and color is needed at this point.